# Is there a way to enforce foreign-key constraints with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a library/layer to use Firestore with, which will generate the correct code for create/update/remove operations, in a way that deals with foreign key constraints. A user would specify a schema like this:

```
struct Game {
   players: List<Player>;
   regions: List<Region>;
}
struct Player {
   occupiedBases: List<&Base>; // & means a foreign reference, this base *must* exist.
}
struct Region {
   bases: List<Base>;
}
struct Base {
   position: Vec2;
}
```

The key requirements involved with & are:

- You can't have a & reference to a node that doesn't exist.
- A node can't be deleted if anyone has an & reference to it.

In other words, it's a foreign key constraint.

I have a rough idea for how to accomplish this:

- Every time a player gets a new &Base, it atomically increments the target Base document's __refCount field.
- Every time someone tries to delete a Base, it checks that the __refCount is 0.

However, there's no such thing as "atomically increment". To do this, I need transactions. But, if I have transactions, then one person modifying __refCount will cause a fail/retry in every other transaction modifying that same __refCount. In other words, __refCount is now a hotspot. If many & references refer to the same node, that will cause some massive slowdowns as they all read/write the same integer.

As I'm getting further down this rabbit hole, I think, this must exist, someone must have done this already. Is there an established good way of doing foreign key constraints like this?

Comment: Generally, if your data has relationships like this, you should be using a relational database (eg SQL based). Firebase, unfortunately, does not provide a relational database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I suspect Firebase is more and more becoming better at the kinds of things relational databases do (they added firestore and transactions after all). Relational databases are of course better at representing this kind of relationship, but relational databases don't offer most things Firebase does (I need no frontend, I can listen in real time, etc). I'm happy to tolerate some awkwardness in shoehorning a relational model into Firebase if it means I can have those amazing other benefits. The question is... how hard will it be? Can we make a library do it for us like this?

Comment: Sure, it's conceivable that you could write a library that runs on top of the Firebase library and enforces relationships. One of the applications I work on stores a lot of relational data in Firebase, and up to now, we've been delicately writing frontend code to enforce these relationships. But this code isn't very portable. It's not very well planned out yet. It has bugs. It makes mistakes. Meanwhile, databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL have had quite a headstart in development time. They also have the benefit of controlling exactly how data is persisted.

Comment: We plan to switch to an SQL database soon (tm).

Comment: I've also tried writing some firebase code to enforce relationships and it was indeed a nightmare (which is why I'm working on this library) so I totally empathize with your move to SQL. If you don't mind me asking, what kind of relationships are you enforcing? The problems you mention are exactly the kind of thing my library wants to address in the distant future, so it would be nice to know some more real-world problems.

Comment: It's an LMS (learning management system). There are lessons which belong to chapters. Lessons can contain various "activities" like a video, text instruction, quiz, etc. Quizzes belong to lessons. Questions belong to quizzes, responses belong to questions. And on top of this, we track what each user has answered for each question, or assessment activity, and which instruction a user has viewed. Lots of relationships! Some of which are even tricky to represent in SQL... but a nightmare to enforce in Firebase.

Comment: Cool, those all sound like foreign key constraints, exactly what I'm attempting to solve! Are there any other relationships you enforce, such as "this number over here must be more than that number over there" etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168591/discussion-between-sidney-and-verdagon).